# Uncaught ReferenceError: localePreference is not defined

Tags: javascript, date, reactjs

I'm using Javascript's `Date()` method to convert ISO to readable formats.

```
formatIsoDate({date}) {
    const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }
    return new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString(options)
}

render() {
    return (
        <p>{formatIsoDate({date: this.props.date})}</p>   
    )
}
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: localePreference is not defined

I'm reading up the docs on Mozilla MDN but I don't see anything there. It says the first parameter of the `toLocaleDateString` *locale* is optional.

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure about the environment this code is in but I don't think it's valid syntax.

Comment: do you have a polyfill somewhere?

Comment: can you put more code. are you using localePreference  somewhere

Comment: There is no such thing as `localePreference` in standard JavaScript. I expect @DanielA.White is on the right track here; you may have a polyfill that does not understand that the first parameter is optional. You could try `toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)` just to see if it works.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, adding the first parameter 'en-US' yields the same error :(

Comment: @DanielA.White no I don't have a polyfill. I just looked it up though, is that related to this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(new Date("11-11-11").toLocaleDateString({ year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }));
```

This statement works fine for me, so the issue isn't `.toLocaleDateString()`. I am uncertain that this code is syntactically sound, maybe you can post more to clarify.

Comment: no , enter this in you console `new Date(undefined).toLocaleDateString`

Comment: Yeah. Hmm. And I can't find the error "localePreference is not defined" anywhere. The javascript usage seems strange -- "return({<p>{stuff}</p>})"?

Comment: he is using react.js

Comment: It may work for you, but for me Firefox returns "Invalid Date" due to the invalid ISO 8601 string, Safari returns "11/13/11" as it ignores the incorrectly specified arguments to "toLocaleDateString" and uses implementation specific heuristics to parse the string (which is per ECMA-262), Opera returns "11/11/2011" likely for the same reason (as does Chrome). So I'm not sure what "works fine" means.

Answer (score 0):

If arguments are provided to [*toLocaleString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring) methods, the first must be an [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646) language tag, e.g. "fr" for french or "fr-acf" for saint lucian creole french. The full list of language and subtags is at [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry), a helpful resource is [r12a >> apps >> Language subtag lookup](https://r12a.github.io/app-subtags/). Also see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

If you don't want to specify the language, use *undefined* and the browser default will be used:

```js
function formatIsoDate(date) {
    var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
    return date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
}

console.log(formatIsoDate(new Date));
```

Not all browsers support options for *toLocaleString*, also the result is implementation dependent and users will likely get different results depending on the browser they're using. E.g for me, Safari returns "March 12, 2017", whereas Firefox returns "12March,2017".

[ECMA-402](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html#sup-date.prototype.tolocalestring) calls the first argument a "locale", which is a misnomer as it represents a language.